# bindparam not working - PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to get the link that it given by my rss script.

My Code with bindParam

```
$items = count($return_data->channel->item);
     for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){
         $link = $desc = $return_data->channel->item[$i]->link;
         $title = $desc = $return_data->channel->item[$i]->title;
         echo $link;
         echo '<hr>';
         // PDO query -> check if news already is in database
         $q1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM runescapenews WHERE link=':link'");
         $q1->bindParam(':link', $link);
         $q1->execute();
         $r1 = $q1->rowCount();
         echo $r1;
         echo '<hr>';
         if($r1 == '0' ){
             echo '0 - Not working';
         }else{
            while($res1 = $q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo $res1['title'];
            }                 
         }
     }
```

Now the problem is that my result is not working :

```
 http://services.runescape.com/m=news/a=135/barrows---rise-of-the-six
 0
 0 - Not working
```

But when i change the `link = ':link'` to `link='$link'` my result will be :

```
http://services.runescape.com/m=news/a=135/barrows---rise-of-the-six
1
Barrows - Rise of the Six
```

So my question is. How can i get it working with bindParam and still get the result i am getting on the result when using $link by prepare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$q1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM runescapenews WHERE link=:link");

Comment: Drop the ' because bindParam does it automatically

Comment: It'd be good if you explained the difference within the answer.

Comment: :link not ':link' because PDO prepared statements work this way

Comment: @JoniSalmi o wow! Thanks its working! sorry for my noobie question.

Comment: @JoniSalmi: I'm well aware of how PDO prepared statements work.  See my profile.  :)  My point was that a line of code with no explanation is a crappy answer.  The stuff you're putting in the comments is a bit more helpful, but comments can disappear.  It'd be better if the answer itself included that info.

Comment: PDO prepared statements works also with single prepare multiple execute.